# Cannot specify setter 'setTitle:' for properties of NSObject or WKInterfaceController

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I am trying to set up a WKInterfaceTable. I followed Apples docs. My Label is not getting text and I get this error message in console:

```
Cannot specify setter 'setTitle:' for properties of NSObject or WKInterfaceController
```

How can I fix this? Objective-C please. Here s my code:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>

@interface MainRowType : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceImage *image;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *title;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "MainRowType.h"

@implementation MainRowType


@end
```

.h

```
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MainRowType.h"

@interface WatchTableController : WKInterfaceController


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceTable *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *titleArray;


@end
```

.m

I call this method

```
- (void)configureTableWithData:(NSMutableArray*)dataObjects {

    [self.tableView setNumberOfRows:[dataObjects count] withRowType:@"mainRowType"];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.tableView.numberOfRows; i++) {
        MainRowType* theRow = [self.tableView rowControllerAtIndex:i];
        NSString *titleString = [dataObjects objectAtIndex:i];

        [theRow.title setText:titleString];

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `title` property is the problem. You can't name a property "title" in those classes. Change the property name and you should be all set.

Comment: I would like to know why "title" can't be used. As far as I know, the only "title" method in NSObject is "func title(for: ABPerson!, identifier: String!)".